# Is it possible to use tag dispatching to determine return type

Tags: c++, templates

Tag dispatch is mentioned in [Switch passed type from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522375/switch-passed-type-from-template).

Is it possible (and how if it is) to do something like:

```
struct Tag1 {};
struct Tag2 {};

template<class T, typename R>
R get();

template<>
double get<Tag1>() {return 1.3;}

template<>
char const *get<Tag2>() {return "hello";}

double aDouble = get<Tag1>();
char const *aString = get<Tag2>();
```

The above code causes the complier to complain about ambiguous call to overloaded function, but I hope the last two lines communicate the intention of usage.

Thx

Comment: What do you mean by "is it possible"? Why not? I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: What's the problem? (Instead of Tag1, Tag2 I'd simply use double and char const* but you may have your reasons).

Comment: Yes I have the case of the return type working, I'm just wondering where the boundaries lie.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same` (C++11), or their boost equivalents:

```
template <typename Tag>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Tag, Tag1>::value, double>::type get()
{ ... }

template <typename Tag>
typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Tag, Tag2>::value, char const *>::type get()
{ ... }
```

Comment: I don't know (I use gcc/clang), you'd have to check.

Comment: If not, use boost -- or, you could code enable_if and is_same yourself (these two guys are not that difficult).

Answer (score 1):

Function templates with different number of template parameters overload each others, so you aren't defining specialization but overload. Something like this should work:

```
struct Tag1 {};
struct Tag2 {};

template<class T> struct MapResult;

template<> struct MapResult<Tag1> { typedef double Result; };
template<> struct MapResult<Tag2> { typedef char const* Result; };

template<class T>
typename MapResult<T>::Result get();

template<> double get<Tag1>() {return 1.2;}
template<> char const *get<Tag2>() {return "hello";}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second template parameter of `get` cannot be deduced because it only appears as the return type: who's to say that `get<Tag1>()` is a call to `get<Tag1, double>` specifically and not e.g. `get<Tag1, int>`? If you were to call e.g. `get<Tag1, double>()` then the call would be resolved to the correct specialization.

However I suspect that you don't really want `get` to be a function template with two template parameters: the return type is perhaps intended to be a function of the first parameter. As such, I suggest you declare `get` like so:

```
namespace result_of {

template<typename T>
struct get;

}

template<typename T>
typename result_of::get<T>::type get();
```

where `result_of::get` is going to be the metafunction that computes the expected result type. To make things simpler, rather than specializing the function template `get` we're going to put all our eggs in the `result_of::get` basket:

```
namespace result_of {

template<typename T>
struct get;

}

template<typename T>
typename result_of::get<T>::type get()
{ return result_of::get<T>::apply(); }

namespace result_of {

template<>
struct get<Tag1> {
    typedef double type;

    static type apply()
    { return 1.3; }
};

template<>
struct get<Tag2> {
    typedef const char* type;

    static type apply()
    { return "hello"; }
};

}
```

In general it's much more common to specialize class templates rather than function templates, and cases where it looks like it is needed to specialize a function template are often made simpler by letting the function template delegate its implementation entirely to a class template.