# Variadic Templates example not compiling

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am trying to grasp and understand the concept of variadic templates.
I came across [this](http://insanecoding.blogspot.com/2010/03/c-201x-variadic-templates.html) example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Output function to output any type without type specifiers like printf() family
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  cout << t << ' ';
  if (sizeof...(p)) { output(p...); }
  else { cout << '\n'; }
}

//Since variadic templates are recursive, must have a base case
void output() { cout << "\n"; }

//Test it
int main()
{
  //output();
  output('5', 2);

  return(0);
}
```

However when I attempt to run it I get the error

```
main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void output(T, P ...) [with T = int; P = {}]':
main.cpp:10:29:   required from 'void output(T, P ...) [with T = char; P = {int}]'
main.cpp:21:16:   required from here
main.cpp:10:29: error: no matching function for call to 'output()'
   if (sizeof...(p)) { output(p...); }
                             ^
main.cpp:7:6: note: candidate: template<class T, class ... P> void output(T, P ...)
 void output(T t, P ...p)
      ^
main.cpp:7:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:10:29: note:   candidate expects at least 1 argument, 0 provided
   if (sizeof...(p)) { output(p...); }
                             ^
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix it. Thanks

Comment: Swap the two `output` overloads.

Comment: That's not _running_, that's _compiling_. I was really wondering how variadic templates could cause a runtime error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch the order of declaration of your output functions:

```
//Since variadic templates are recursive, must have a base case
void output() { cout << "\n"; }

//Output function to output any type without type specifiers like printf() family
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  cout << t << ' ';
  if (sizeof...(p)) { output(p...); }
  else { cout << '\n'; }
}
```

The overload resolution rules get funky for template functions, so the compiler only considered the overloads that had been declared so far, and didn't consider your non-template. When writing several overloads, where one or more of them are template functions, declaration order matters.

Comment: Could you explain what was going on ?

Answer (score 2):

It's more complicated than just declaration order.  See this answer: [Switch passed type from template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522375/switch-passed-type-from-template/4522439#4522439)

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  cout << t << ' ';
  if (sizeof...(p)) { output(p...); } // HERE
  else { cout << '\n'; }
}
```

Regardless of whether or not the function is actually called it must exist.  You can't have a branch within a function that though never executed results in a syntax error.  Your check for `sizeof...(p)` is thus kinda pointless.

So to make your code clearer, in that it expresses itself completely and doesn't have extra stuff, change to this:

```
void output() { cout << "\n"; }

//Output function to output any type without type specifiers like printf() family
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  cout << t << ' ';
  output(p...);
}
```

You also don't have to define them in that order, though it's easier.  You could do this:

```
void output();

//Output function to output any type without type specifiers like printf() family
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  cout << t << ' ';
  output(p...);
}

void output() { cout << "\n"; }
```

Or even this:

```
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  void output();
  cout << t << ' ';
  output(p...);
}

void output() { cout << "\n"; }
```

Edit: Actually, you can avoid the need for a 0 parameter version:

```
template < typename T >
void output(T t) { cout << t << "\n"; }

//Output function to output any type without type specifiers like printf() family
template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p)
{
  cout << t << ' ';
  output(p...);
}
```

Comment: The last one won't work. The local `output` declaration hides the template.

Answer (score 1):

`T t` will be the first argument and `P ...p` the rest.

```
output('5', 2);
//          ^
```

You put the function `void output()` below, and it's not *visible*.

To fix this, you can declare the function above so that it will be seen:

```
void output();
```

Or move the function with no parameters above the other one:

```
void output() { cout << "\n"; }

template <typename T, typename ...P>
void output(T t, P ...p) { // ... }
```