# How to store a templated function in a .cpp file?

Tags: c++, function, templates

I have a header file that looks like this

```
// header.hpp
namespace n {
template <typename T>
T someFunc(int some_val);
}
```

and an implementation that seems to be incorrect:

```
// body.cpp
#include "header.hpp"
namespace n {
template int someFunc<int>(int some_val) {...}
template bool someFunc<bool>(int some_val) {...}
}
```

**Question:** How can I write type-specific implementations in a .cpp-file, if I have the definition of my templated function in the header?

**Why do I want this?:** In my case, `someFunc` calls different functions, depending on the type of `T`. So it is not truly generic, which is why I would like to have several implementations (an alternative would be to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4522375/switch-passed-type-from-template))

**Sorry**, for asking this simple question, but I only found solutions that explain how to store templated class-member-functions in .cpp files (compare [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115703/storing-c-template-function-definitions-in-a-cpp-file)).

Comment: Dude! That is the same post I am linking to! It explains how to do that for templated classes. `someFunc` is not a function of a class.

Comment: As pointed out in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file, there is an alternative solution for classes. Is there one for functions that are not part of a class?

Comment: What happens when you compile your template? Do you get any errors? If so, what are they?

Comment: explicit template instantiation cannot have a definition; if this definition is meant to be an explicit specialization, add '<>' after the 'template' keyword

Comment: So the solution is to just write `template<int>` and template<bool>`?

Comment: Your templates evaluate to multiple `someFunc`'s with differing return types. You cannot overload on return types.

Comment: See also this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8133000/1387438

Comment: @BradyDean Well, I could just call `someFunc<int>(...)` and  `someFunc<bool>(...)`, right?